# I keep getting a Bad request error when trying to post Image to Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

i'm trying to upload an image to cloudinary using `axios` and `react`. I have two functions. One for appending the formData, and the other for making a request

```
// APPEND CLOUDINARY DETAILS
export function appendCloudinaryDetails(fileUrl){
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("api_key", 'APIKEYHERE');
  formData.append("api_secret", 'APISECRETHERE');
  formData.append("file", 'fileUrl');
  formData.append("cloud_name", fileUrl);
  formData.append("upload_preset", "rhi2i6xg");    
  return formData;
}

// STORE THE DATA ON CLOUDINARY
export function storeOnCloudinary(formData){
  return () => {
    return axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/my-company/image/upload", formData,{
      headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    });
  }
}
```

And this is how i use it:

```
// Append Cloudinary Details
let formData = appendCloudinaryDetails(this.state.backdropCroppedImageUrl);

// Store the backdrop on Cloudinary
this.props.storeOnCloudinary(formData).then(
   response => {
     ...
   }
);
```

But running this gives me a `400` error response. As shown below:

[image]

Comment: Is there any response from the server? And I hope what you posted is not your real api_key and api_secret...

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading and what is the max file upload size allowed by your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a faithful copy of your code, or it was changed in order to hide sensitive information in the posted question, but according to it, you are appending to the formData the `backdropCroppedImageUrl` as the 'cloud_name' instead of setting it on 'file', and in 'file' you're setting a string.